# Page not found (404) Directory indexes are not allowed here. in Django after gives path

Tags: django, url

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZOaV.png)

Using the URLconf defined in ebook.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
Guest/
Admin/
BookAuthor/
^(?P.*)$
The empty path matched the last one.

i'm looking for an solutions ...

Comment: Can you update your question with more details to help us debug the issue with you?
Can you add the `urls.py`?